# Python geradores assincronos

Tags: python, python-3.x, async

Com a introdução da biblioteca `asyncio`, uma nova sintaxe foi introduzida para definição de corotinas no Python >= 3.5 e com ela é possível definir métodos assíncronos, iteradores assíncronos e até mesmo geradores assíncronos.

Como posso implementar geradores assíncronos e quais seriam seus casos de uso comum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A melhor fonte de informação sobre geradores assíncronos é a PEP que descreve sua necessidade,e sua implementação - a [PEP 525](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0525/).

Para descrever brevemente geradores assíncronos, vamos recapitular brevemente o *uso* de funções assíncronas (mas não seu mecanismo interno).
Código assíncrono em Python e em outras linguagens se caracteríza por código capaz de ser executado numa única thread, mas em que o programador possa colocar pontos *explícitos* em que o código de uma função (gerador, método, etc...) pode ser pausado enquanto aguarda um resultado. Durante essa pausa, um "controlador" da execução do código assíncrono passa a execução para outras funções assíncronas pausadas da mesma forma, checa se chegaram resultados que estão sendo esperados, etc... .

Em Python essa pausa é caracterizada pelas palavras chave `await` e `async` - sempre que uma delas aparece no corpo de uma função , o código ` *deve* estar sendo executado num contexto assíncrono.

Acontece que em Python 3.5 já tinha sido definido o comando `async for` - ou seja, um `for` onde a cada ineração o controle do programa é passado para o loop de eventos, até o próximo elemento do iterador estar disponível.  O iterador para ser usado num `async for` em Python 3.5 teria que definir os métodos especiais `__aiter__` e `__anext__` como co-rotinas (funções assícronas, declaradas com `async def`)- em contraste com os `__iter__` e `__next__` de iteradores normais.

Só que para um `for` normal, não assíncrono, qualquer função que contenha a expressão `yield` em seu corpo é convertida autmaticamente num `generator`: ou seja, um objeto que tem os métodos `__iter__` e `__next__` e pode ser usado num  `for`. Um `async for`, antes do Python 3.6 e da PEP 525, só poderia iterar sobre uma classe definida com as versões assincronas desses métodos, e tentar usar, no corpo de uma função assíncrona, a expressão `yield`, resultava num erro de sintaxe:

```
Python 3.5.5 (default, Jun  8 2018, 09:55:12) 
...
>>> async def a():
...    yield 1
... 
  File "<stdin>", line 2
SyntaxError: 'yield' inside async function
```

Apenas no Python 3.6 é possível declarar diretamente um async generator:

```
Python 3.6.5 (default, Jun  8 2018, 09:56:48) 
...
>>> async def a():
...    yield 1
... 
>>>
```

E ele é usável, em outra função assíncrona, sempre gerenciada pelo loop de eventos, pelo comando `async for`:

```
import asyncio

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

import random
async def random_pause_generator(start, stop):
    for i in range(start, stop):
        await asyncio.sleep(random.random())
        yield i

async def counter(start, stop):
    async for j in random_pause_generator(start, stop):
        print(j)


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(counter(0, 10), counter(110, 120))

loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Execute esse código e note como as duas chamadas à co-rotina "counter" são executadas em paralelo, com resultados de cada chamada aparecendo fora de ordem. É interessante notar a chamada a `asyncio.gather` que unifica a espera das duas chamadas numa "espera única". Se for usado simplesmente `await counter(10, 20)`, o resultado final é o mesmo que numa função síncrona: o programa só prosseguiria na linha de baixo após a chamada a `counter` se resolver por completo.

Nota extra sobre async: o código controlador em Python é referido simplesmente pelo "loop de eventos", e é um objeto especial que, no caso de uso da biblioteca asyncio sempre pode ser recuperado pela chamada `asyncio.get_event_loop` . (Note que é **possível** ter outras implementações de bibliotecas para coordenar a execução de código assíncrono, e que podem ter chamadas distintas para se recuperar o loop de eventos - mas uma vez que a asyncio é flexível o bastante para permitir o uso de outras classes como loop de eventos, isso é seria só reinventar a roda)