# Python palavra reservada yield

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, yield

Qual a diferença entre os seguintes códigos ?

```
def bottom():
    yield 42

def bottom():
    return (yield 42)
```

Comment: Eu sei o que faz yield mas encontro scripts onde vem associado a um return, nessa resposta só está informando a função do yield não porque o mesmo vem associado ao return

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O primeiro caso retorna um gerador, que é um objeto que contém um enumerador, tem um estado de onde esse enumerador está. Quem chamar a função pode pegar o resultado do enumerador. Isto é transparente e dará 42.

No segundo caso o `yield` retorna o enumerador da sua expressão ali mesmo e depois o resultado desse enumerador é retornado da função, já é o 42.

Na prática não muda nada, neste caso, mas o mecanismo interno é bem diferente.

Pode ver mais em: [Para que serve o Yield?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/101).

Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura.

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta Maniero

Comment: Como 'na prática não muda nada", se muda? Para obter o 42 no segundo caso, tem que se chamar um método do generator retornado: `next(bottom())` - então muda bastante coisa de `bottom()`.

Comment: então - a história completa é um pouco mais complicada que isso.

Comment: @jsbueno não tenho dúvida disso, mas nãis entrar nisso pq ele parece ñ ter entendimento suficiente ainda pra saber em mais detalhes, e vc tem mais condições de falar dos *internals* de Python do que eu. o Resumo é este.

Answer (score 6):

Resumidamente, *esse é o mecanismo utilizado para que co-rotinas possam retornar valores no Python* - detalhes de como funciona seguem abaixo:

Primeiro: se o corpo de uma função tem a palavra chave `yield`, `yield from` ou é declarada como `async def`, o `return` *não funciona* como um return normal. O que é retornado quando se chama uma função dessas como se fosse uma função normal é uma co-rotina ou um generator:

```
>>> def a():
...     return (yield 42)
...  

>>> a()
<generator object a at 0x7fc904b167d8>
```

O valor do resultado - o que se encontra no `return` - de um generator ou co-rotina aparece como o atributo `.value` da Exceção `StopIteration` causada pelo iterador.

Ou seja, este código:

```
def a():
    return (yield 42)
try:
    b.send("final value")
except StopIteration as end:
    end2 = end

print(end2.value)
```

Vai imprimir "initial value". Note que esse mecanismo raramente vai ser usado diretamente pelo programador, e é usado internamente pelo código de suporte a código assíncrono.

O método `send` foi introduzido ainda no Python 2, uma versão depois da criação da palavra chave `yield` - acredito que no Python 2.5 - e permite que se envie valores de volta para dentro do generator (como o valor final da expressão `yield`). A partir desse mecanismo, e mais o método `.throw` que permite causar uma exceção onde está o `yield`, permitiram que os generators passassem a funcionar como co-rotinas.

Um uso mais direto acontece quando o generator for usado de dentro de outro generator, com a forma `yield from`. Nesse caso, o valor retornado como resultado do `yield from` é o valor de `return` do gerador mais interno. Ou seja: o código abaixo imprime "None" (que é o resultado do `yield` na função anterior quando é usado apenas com `next`:

```
def c():
    value = yield from a()
    print(value)
    return None

[_ for _ in c()]
```

Se você esta vendo código que não utiliza programação assíncrona, e tem valores de `return` dentro de corpos de funções com `yield` provavelmente esses generators estão sendo usados dessa forma.

Então, esse mecanismo de separar o valor de retorno dentro da exceção que indica o final do generator foi a forma encontrada dessas co-rotinas gerarem um valor final, enquanto que o `yield` dentro das mesmas passa a servir não para gerar um valor significativo, como no caso de generators comuns, mas para ser um ponto de *pausa* dessas funções. As co-rotinas são chamadas sempre, ao contrário dos generators, por um código mais complexo responsável por coordenar sua chamada, e chamar outras co-rotinas - esse é  o mecanismo usado no `asyncio` - a biblioteca oficial para execução de código assíncrono no Python. Esse código coordenador é o "event loop" - laço de eventos - do programa que funciona de forma assíncrona.

Nesse caso, o código que usa o generator não é chamado diretamente - ele é chamado de dentro de outras co-rotinas com a palavra chave `await`, ou é agendado no *event loop*, de forma que devolva um resultado quando terminar. (O *event loop* faz toda a coordenação para pegar o `.value` do StopIteration, ou lançar uma exceção na co-rotina de forma correta, e chamar outras co-rotinas quando o código é "pausado" por um "yield from" ou "await")

Em Python 3.4, o uso do decorator  `asyncio.coroutine` marcava um generator usando `yield from` para funcionar como co-rotina. Então se você tem código assíncrono feito para funcionar com Python 3.4 (ou emular isso com Python 2.7), ele vai fazer uso do `yield from` para chamar outras co-rotinas em seu corpo, e usar o `return` para retornar o resultado final .  A partir do Python 3.5 foi criada uma sintaxe especializada - como descrito acima. As co-rotinas passam a ser declaradas com `async def` em vez de precisar do decorator `coroutine`, e a palavra chave `await` é usada no lugar do `yield from`. (Em suma, em outras co-rotinas chamadas, o valor no "return" é o retornado "normalmente" para uma função chamada na forma `valor = await funcao()`.

Escrevi recentemente uma outra resposta extensa onde falo de mais alguns aspectos da programação assíncrona - dê uma olhada lá: [Python geradores assincronos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/308516/python-geradores-assincronos/309038#309038)