# Por que criar uma lista com o mesmo gerador só funciona da primeira vez?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

No Python 3.6.8, quando eu materializo a lista, ela é mostrada e se apaga. Isso é um bug ou é assim mesmo?

```py
>>> vet_neg
['EH01', 'EH02', 'EH03']
Categories (3, object): ['EH01', 'EH02', 'EH03']
>>> cenarios
[0, 1]
>>> vet_neg_cenarios = itertools.product(vet_neg, cenarios, cenarios)
>>> vet_neg_cenarios
<itertools.product object at 0x7f6fa16a65e8>
>>> list(vet_neg_cenarios)
[('EH01', 0, 0), ('EH01', 0, 1), ('EH01', 1, 0), ('EH01', 1, 1), ('EH02', 0, 0), ('EH02', 0, 1), ('EH02', 1, 0), ('EH02', 1, 1), ('EH03', 0, 0), ('EH03', 0, 1), ('EH03', 1, 0), ('EH03', 1, 1)]
>>> list(vet_neg_cenarios)
[]
>>>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Da forma que fez, é assim mesmo.

Internamente, a função `itertools.product` trabalhará com geradores e, por definição, um gerador só poderá ser consumido apenas uma vez.

- [Como o Python trata o comando “yield” internamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365978/5878)
- [Python palavra reservada yield](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/309366/5878)
- [Para que serve o Yield?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/5878)

Quando você faz `list(vet_neg_cenarios)` na primeira vez, o gerador será consumido completamente para que todos os valores gerados sejam armazenados na sua lista. Depois de exausto - consumido por completo - o gerador não terá mais valores para gerar e, portanto, `list(vet_neg_cenarios)` será uma lista vazia.

Se realmente precisa manter em memória, atribua o resultado da primeira `list(vet_neg_cenarios)` a um objeto.

Comment: Não preciso manter. Eu tinha colocado um print antes de um loop para futuros debuges e isso surgiu.

Answer (score 2):

O que você tem é um generator e o valor em questão apaga da memória depois que você usa. Por exemplo, os elementos da variável:

```
pares=(k for k in range(10) if k%2==0)
```

podem ser acessados pelo método `pares.__next__()`, mas depois de chamar 5 vezes ele para de funcionar. Veja:

```py
In [2]: pares.__next__()
Out[2]: 0

In [3]: pares.__next__()
Out[3]: 2

In [4]: pares.__next__()
Out[4]: 4

In [5]: pares.__next__()
Out[5]: 6

In [6]: pares.__next__()
Out[6]: 8

In [7]: pares.__next__()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-fa4a719088da> in <module>
----> 1 pares.__next__()

StopIteration:
```

Note que no seu caso, se você rodar `print(vet_neg_cenarios.__next__())` o programa vai printar o primeiro elemento da lista. Quando você chamou o método `list` no generator, você consumiu todos os elementos de uma vez.