# Variável parece só funcionar uma vez

Tags: python, sistema-de-arquivos, iterator

Eu tenho uma pasta com vários relatórios dentro, no meu windows, e basicamente o que quero fazer é percorrer todos os arquivos da pasta, identificar de qual estado é aquele relatório, criar uma pasta para cada estado que possua o relatório, em seguida mover cada um dos relatórios para dentro de sua respectiva pasta, de acordo o estado de cada um.

Download: [Arquivos da Pasta](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sz2IJYfmUWJvkJnVlwLhJmLIrjVxV-DM/view?usp=sharing)

OBS: Código completo ao final

O problema que estou enfrentando é que, na sessão #IDENTIFICANDO ESTADOS, eu fiz o seguinte:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

caminho = Path('E:/Arquivos_Lojas')
arquivos = caminho.iterdir()

#IDENTIFICANDO ESTADOS

estados = []
for arquivo in arquivos:
    if arquivo.name[-6:-4] in estados:
        pass
    else:
        estados.append(arquivo.name[-6:-4])
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E até aqui tudo bem, o `for` percorre normalmente a variável com a lista dos arquivos que existem dentro da pasta, e em seguida adiciona o nomes dos estados que possuem relatórios na lista *estados*.

Porém ao tentar usar o mesmo `for` novamente, dessa vez na sessão #MOVENDO ARQUIVOS PARA AS PASTAS, afim de verificar se X arquivo é referente a X pasta de determinado estado, simplesmente não acontece nada no código, não faz o que deveria fazer e nem acusa erro:

```
#MOVENDO ARQUIVOS PARA AS PASTAS (NÃO FUNCIONA)

for arquivo in arquivos:
    for pasta in arquivos:
        if arquivo.name[-6:-4] == pasta.name:
            shutil.move(Path(arquivo), Path(caminho/pasta.name/arquivo.name))
        else:
            pass
```

O curioso é que ao substituir a variável na função pelo valor que ela deveria possuir, o código começa a funcionar perfeitamente:

```
#MOVENDO ARQUIVOS PARA AS PASTAS (FUNCIONA)

for arquivo in Path('E:/Arquivos_Lojas').iterdir():
    for pasta in Path('E:/Arquivos_Lojas').iterdir():
        if arquivo.name[-6:-4] == pasta.name:
            shutil.move(Path(arquivo), Path(caminho/pasta.name/arquivo.name))
        else:
            pass
```

Gostaria de saber que tipo de problema é esse que aconteceu e onde que errei para que a variável só funcionasse uma vez ou seja o que for que está acontecendo.

Aqui está o Código completo funcionando:

```
from pathlib import Path
import shutil

caminho = Path('E:/Arquivos_Lojas')
arquivos = caminho.iterdir()

#IDENTIFICANDO ESTADOS

estados = []
for arquivo in arquivos:
    if arquivo.name[-6:-4] in estados:
        pass
    else:
        estados.append(arquivo.name[-6:-4])

if '' in estados:
    estados.remove('')
else:
    pass
        
#CRIANDO AS PASTAS

for pasta in estados:
    if Path(caminho/pasta).exists():
        print('A Pasta {} já existe'.format(pasta))
    else:
        Path(caminho/pasta).mkdir()
        
#MOVENDO ARQUIVOS PARA AS PASTAS

for arquivo in Path('E:/Arquivos_Lojas').iterdir():
    for pasta in Path('E:/Arquivos_Lojas').iterdir():
        if arquivo.name[-6:-4] == pasta.name:
            shutil.move(Path(arquivo), Path(caminho/pasta.name/arquivo.name))
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: `else: pass` é completamente desnecessário. Se não vai fazer nada no `else`, simplesmente **não coloque o `else`**. De forma similar, o primeiro `if` com `pass` também é esquisito, bastaria inverter a condição: `if arquivo.name[-6:-4] not in estados: estados.append(arquivo.name[-6:-4])` - se bem que, para evitar elementos duplicados, seria melhor que `estados` fosse um `set` em vez de uma lista... Mas na verdade, eu acho que vc está complicando à toa, pois daria para mover os arquivos em um único loop: https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/MoverArquivos#main.py

Answer (score 2):

Como a pergunta não se trata por busca por correção e sim elucidação de conceito deixo 2 avisos:

> **Aviso1**
> Não vejo com bons olhos o método como são extraídos as siglas dos Estados dos
> nomes dos arquivos através de slices de [`PurePath.name`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.name) pois
> arquivos Excel podem vir com [extensões em diferentes números de caracteres](https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/windows/extens%C3%B5es-de-nome-de-arquivo-comuns-no-windows-da4a4430-8e76-89c5-59f7-1cdbbc75cb01).
> Seria mais portável a verificação das [extensões dos arquivos](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.suffix) e posterior uso de slices a partir do retorno do método [`PurePath.stem()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.stem) que obtém a componente final do caminho, sem a extensão.

> **Aviso2**
> Ao trabalhar com sistema de arquivos teste antes de manipular a natureza dos objetos a serem processados assim evitando operações ilegais e redundâncias de operações. Veja as funções [`Path.is_dir()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_dir) , [`Path.is_file()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_file) , [`Path.is_mount()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_mount) , [`Path.is_symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_symlink) , [`Path.is_socket()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_socket), [`Path.is_fifo()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_fifo) , [`Path.is_block_device()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_block_device) e [`Path.is_char_device()`](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.is_char_device)

O método [`Path.iterdir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.iterdir), quando o `Path` estiver apontado para um diretório, retorna um [**iterador**](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) que retorna o conteúdo de diretório.

Se procurar no glossário da linguagem no [verbete iterador](https://docs.python.org/pt-br/3/glossary.html#term-iterator) irá encontrar:

> Um objeto que representa um fluxo de dados. Repetidas chamadas ao
> método `__next__()` de um iterador (ou passando o objeto para a função
> embutida `next()`) vão retornar itens sucessivos do fluxo.
> **Quando não houver mais dados disponíveis uma exceção `StopIteration` será
> levantada. Neste ponto, o objeto iterador se esgotou e quaisquer
> chamadas subsequentes a seu método `__next__()` vão apenas levantar a
> exceção `StopIteration` novamente.** Iteradores precisam ter um método
> `__iter__()` que retorne o objeto iterador em si, de forma que todo iterador também é iterável e pode ser usado na maioria dos lugares em
> que um iterável é requerido. Uma notável exceção é código que tenta
> realizar passagens em múltiplas iterações. Um objeto contêiner (como
> uma `list`) produz um novo iterador a cada vez que você passá-lo para a
> função `iter`() ou utilizá-lo em um laço `for`. **Tentar isso com o mesmo
> iterador apenas iria retornar o mesmo objeto iterador esgotado já
> utilizado na iteração anterior, como se fosse um contêiner vazio.**

Ou seja ao buscar os itens de um iterador serão feitas repetidas chamadas ao seu método `__next__()` e quando não houver mais dados disponíveis diz-se que o iterador está esgotado e qualquer tentativa de reutilizar um iterador já esgotado é inútil pois esse se comporta como um contêiner vazio.

No seu código a variável `arquivos` referência ao iterador retornado por uma chamada de `Path.iterdir()`:

```
arquivos = caminho.iterdir()
```

Quando itera `arquivos` você está compartilhando um iterador entre dois laços de iteração. Supondo que seu diretório possua mais de dois arquivos, do primeiro laço(externo) você obterá no um elemento enquanto no laço aninhado o iterador `arquivos` será exaurido com os elementos restantes fazendo com que a comparação `arquivo.name[-6:-4] == pasta.name` não funcione como espera.

```
for arquivo in arquivos:
    for pasta in arquivos:
        if arquivo.name[-6:-4] == pasta.name:
            shutil.move(Path(arquivo), Path(caminho/pasta.name/arquivo.name))
        else:
            pass
```

Um resultado similar pode visto nesse exemplo simples onde é criado um iterador a partir de uma sequencia que passa a ser consumido por dois laço de iteração imprimindo o ordem em que os elementos são extraídos do iterador:

```
r = iter(range(10))  #Cria um iterador r no intervalo [0,10[
 
for a in r:          #Retorna apenas o primeiro item do iterador r...
    for b in r:      #Exaure o iterador r...
        print(a,b)
#0 1
#0 2
#0 3
#0 4
#0 5
#0 6
#0 7
#0 8
#0 9
```

<sup>Teste o exemplo no [ide.one](https://ideone.com/CfOwdb)</sup>

Como observação, além da forma como fez o contorno no seu código iterando por dois iteradores distintos apontando para a mesma pasta:

```
for arquivo in Path('E:/Arquivos_Lojas').iterdir():
    for pasta in Path('E:/Arquivos_Lojas').iterdir():
        if arquivo.name[-6:-4] == pasta.name:
            shutil.move(Path(arquivo), Path(caminho/pasta.name/arquivo.name))
        else:
            pass
```

Outro contorno seria na declaração da variável `arquivo` transforma o iterador em uma lista:

```
arquivos = lista(caminho.iterdir())
.
.
.
#Agora o código a seguir se comportará da maneira que espera.
for arquivo in arquivos:
    for pasta in arquivos:
        if arquivo.name[-6:-4] == pasta.name:
            shutil.move(Path(arquivo), Path(caminho/pasta.name/arquivo.name))
        else:
            pass
```

O contorno acima pode ser visto em pratica no exemplo simplificado:

```
r = list(iter(range(10)))   #O iterador agora foi convertido em um alista.
 
for a in r:
    for b in r:
        print(a,b)
#0 0
#0 1
#0 2
#0 3
#0 4
#0 5
#0 6
#0 7
#0 8
#0 9
#1 0
#1 1
#1 2
#1 3
#1 4
#1 5
#1 6
#1 7
#1 8
#1 9
#2 0
.
.
.
#9 9
```

<sup>Testeo exemplo no [ide.one](https://ideone.com/bbjfdk)</sup>

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/498644/112052