# Como o Python trata funções comuns e funções lambdas internamente?

Tags: python, funções, característica-linguagem, expressões-lambda, python-internals

Estou examinando as funções lambdas do Python em comparação com as funções comuns que usa o `def` para cria-las.

Veja um exemplo de uma função comum que converte um numero para binário:

```
def decimalParaBinario(valor, zerosEsquerda=0): 
    return format(valor, 'b').zfill(zerosEsquerda)
```

O tipo dela:

```
print(type(decimalParaBinario))
```

seria:

```
<class 'function'>
```

Sendo que a função `decimalParaBinario` é um objeto da classe `function`. Agora perceba o mesmo comportamento com uma expressão lambda:

```
b = lambda x, n=0 : format(x, 'b').zfill(n)
```

O tipo da lambda seria o mesmo `class 'function'` para a lambda com o nome `b`. E diferente das funções comuns a lambda pode ser anônima, por exemplo:

```
print(lambda x=1, n=8 : format(x, 'b').zfill(n))
```

que retornaria:

```
<function <lambda> at 0x7fae8de04158>
```

Uma referencia à lambda na memória, no qual não há um *nome* explicito para função lambda. Perceba também que o comportamento é diferente de uma função comum, quando expresso uma função lambda como parâmetro de outra função que não esperaria uma função lambda.

Apesar disso, eu ainda não consigo visualizar em minha mente como o Python trata *internamente* uma função comum `def` em relação as expressões `lambda`.

---

## Pergunta

- Como o Python trata funções comuns e funções lambdas internamente?

Comment: No STO em ingles tem essa pergunta e concordo com a [resposta aceita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12264881/2879341), concordo tb com o Luciano Ramalho que diz em, [fluent python](https://www.amazon.com/Fluent-Python-Concise-Effective-Programming/dp/1491946008): "A sintaxe de lambda é somente um açucar sintático: uma expressão lambda cria um objeto função assim como def", além disso concordo tb qdo ele diz: "...As funções anonimas raramente tem utilidade em python. As restrições sintáticas tendem a deixar lambdas não triviais, ilegiveis ou impraticáveis" .

Comment: Muito interessante esse [método para refatorar o uso de lambdas](https://docs.python.org/dev/howto/functional.html#small-functions-and-the-lambda-expression) 1. Escreva um comentário explicando que raio essa lambda faz; 2. Estude o comentario e pense em um nome que capture a essencia do mesmo; 3. Converta o lambda para um def, usando esse nome; 4. Remova o comentário. :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Ambos os tipos de função são idênticos e tratados da mesma forma:

Depois de criadas na memória da aplicação em Python, isso é, uma vez que o código que cria a função - tando uma com `def` quanto uma com `lambda` é executado, **não há** qualquer diferença entre uma função lambda e uma função não lambda.

As duas tem o mesmo tipo, comportamento, e podem ser passadas como parâmetros em qualquer lugar que aceite um "objeto chamável" (callable) como parâmetro.

Tanto não há diferença que a forma "formal e bem educada" de se verificar se um objeto é uma função: importar o módulo `types` e chamar `isinstance(meu_objeto, types.FunctionType)` usa esse `FunctionType` que é definido no arquivo `types.py` da biblioteca padrão do Python exatamente como `FunctionType = type(lambda: None)` - ou seja, funções declaradas com `def` são, em código bem comportado que pode ser usado em produção, etc... comparadas com o tipo de funções `lambda`.

A única diferença (depois de criadas) realmente é que quando se usa `def`, há um nome implícito e obrigatório para a função, que é guardado no atributo `__name__` da mesma. Em funções `lambda`, o `__name__` contém sempre a string `'<lambda>'`. (Note que esse atributo pode ser escrito a vontade, no entanto).

## Por que a diferença mostrada na pergunta então?

Perceba que nos seus `print` na questão, você imprimiu duas coisas diferentes: ao imprimir dados sobre a "função com def", você imprimiu apenas o `type` da função. Ao imprimir dados sobre a "função lambda", você imprimiu a representação da própria função (a instância da `class 'function'`).

Veja no terminal interativo se imprimirmos as mesmas coisas sobre cada função:

```
In [30]: def a(): pass                                                                                                         

In [31]: b = lambda: None                                                                                                      

In [32]: print(a, type(a), a.__name__)                                                                                         
<function a at 0x7f5c8ff466a8> <class 'function'> a

In [33]: print(b, type(b), b.__name__)                                                                                         
<function <lambda> at 0x7f5c8ff06f28> <class 'function'> <lambda>
```

A sua grande preocupação de que "a função lambda é anônima" não faz diferença alguma em qualquer código Python onde vá se fazer uso de uma função - e isso quer dizer que provavelmente você não entendeu algum outro ponto da linguagem.
Aí entra uma discussão legal. Embora a maior parte dos textos, e mesmo a documentação oficial fale sempre em "variáveis", formalmente em Python não temos "variáveis": temos *nomes* para objetos. Um objeto pode ter vários nomes, ou nenhum - o que conta mesmo é quantas referências temos pra um objeto. O comando `def` cria um "nome" para a função que é criada com o mesmo, da mesma forma que um sinal de `=` cria um "nome" para o objeto que é o resultado da expressão a direita do sinal. (Veja acima, tanto "a" quanto "b" podem ser usados da mesma forma - cada nome é criado de um jeito). Outros comandos que criam nomes para objetos são, por exemplo, o  `import`, o `for`, `with` e `class`. Cada um desses cria um ou mais nomes para objetos, e durante a execução do programa, depois que os nomes foram criados, **não há diferença** sobre como o nome foi criado.

Por exemplo, eu posso criar uma função "a" com "def", associar ela a outro nome com o sinal de `=`, e apagar o nome original - ela continua funcionando:

```
In [34]: def a(): 
    ...:     print("função a") 
    ...:                                                                                                                       

In [35]: b = a                                                                                                                 

In [36]: del a                                                                                                                 

In [37]: a()                                                                                                                   
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-37-8d7b4527e81d> in <module>
----> 1 a()

NameError: name 'a' is not defined

In [38]: b()                                                                                                                   
função a
```

Na verdade, podemos ir além - uma função não precisa ter um nome (bem como qualquer objeto Python) - eu posso inserir a função, como qualquer outro objeto numa lista. apagar o nome `b`,  e ela continua funcionando:

```
In [39]: c = [b,]                                                                                                              

In [40]: del b                                                                                                                 

In [41]: c                                                                                                                     
Out[41]: [<function __main__.a()>]

In [42]: c[0]()                                                                                                                
função a
```

(Uma lista ou qualquer outra estrutura de dados - dicionário, atributo em uma instância, etc...). 
A única coisa, que acaba sendo só um detalhe mesmo, é que a função é um objeto que tem o atributo `__name__`, que quando ela é criada com `def` contém o nome dado no comando `def` e quando é criada com lambda sempre contém ''. Mas depois de criada a função, é um atributo quase normalzinho, a única restrição é que deve ser setado para uma string. (Isso é: se você tentar fazer `a.__name__ = None`, por exemplo, o Python dá um  `TypeError`)

## Diferenças entre funções *antes* de serem criadas:

Na Sintaxe da linguagem Python sim, há diferença entre funções com `def` e funções `lambda`: as primeiras podem conter um bloco de código arbitrário, com linhas contendo comandos (como `for`, `if`, `raise`), e, para retornar um valor, devem conter o comando `return`. Já funções `lambda` devem necessariamente ser escritas em *uma única expressão*: isso é, o corpo de uma função lambda pode chamar funções, fazer operações, usar o `if` no modo ternário, conter generator expressions, etc... mas não pode conter nenhum *comando*. O *resultado* dessa expressão é automaticamente o valor de retorno da função lambda.
O compilador de Python, que pode ser chamado manualmente para qualquer string com a função `compile`, tem a distinção de 3 modos: o modo que executa blocos, o modo que executa expressões e o modo "linha de comando", feito para compilar expressões digitadas no ambiente interativo.  O primeiro modo é usado pelo `exec` e o segundo pelo `eval` - que em geral são usados em vez de `compile`, que é mais baixo nível - mas você pode checar na documentação: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile

**segue informação avançada - fiquem a vontade para pular para a próxima sessão se estiver complicado demais**: O interessante é que essa diferença só existe no momento em que um arquivo é *compilado* - ou seja, no momento em que o Python lê o arquivo ".py" como um arquivo de texto e o processa, ele faz essa distinção - logo em seguida é criado o arquivo de bytecode (".pyc", que nas versões recentes fica dentro das pastas `__pycache__`.) Nesses arquivos, o corpo das funções já está compilado num objeto chamado `code object` (`types.CodeType`), e as funções lambda **já são indistinguíveis** de funções com "def", (lembrando: exceto pelo atributo `__name__`). Detalhe que as funções sequer existem nos arquivos .pyc - os objetos Function só são criados na memória quando a execução do programa chegar nas linhas com o bloco `def` ou com a palavra chave `lambda`, mas a sequência de operações no bytecode para criar as mesmas é idêntica.

É possível ver isso usando o "disassembler" da biblioteca padrão em uma função que defina, internamente, uma função de cada:

```
In [57]: def exemplo(): 
    ...:     def a(): 
    ...:         pass 
    ...:     b = lambda: None 
    ...:                                                                                                                       

In [58]: import dis                                                                                                            

In [59]: dis.dis(exemplo)                                                                                                      
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (<code object a at 0x7f5c9c738b70, file "<ipython-input-57-4845f3e66234>", line 2>)
              2 LOAD_CONST               2 ('exemplo.<locals>.a')
              4 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
              6 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  4           8 LOAD_CONST               3 (<code object <lambda> at 0x7f5c8fe44270, file "<ipython-input-57-4845f3e66234>", line 4>)
             10 LOAD_CONST               4 ('exemplo.<locals>.<lambda>')
             12 MAKE_FUNCTION            0
             14 STORE_FAST               1 (b)
             16 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             18 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object a at 0x7f5c9c738b70, file "<ipython-input-57-4845f3e66234>", line 2>:
  3           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE

Disassembly of <code object <lambda> at 0x7f5c8fe44270, file "<ipython-input-57-4845f3e66234>", line 4>:
  4           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Veja que a sequência é: colocar na pilha da VM o "code object", colocar na pilha o nome - e o nome do lambda já aparece aí - e chamar o opcode `MAKE_FUNCTION`.

## Mas e então, existem "funções fundamentalmente diferentes"?

A resposta é *sim*. Há poucos dias você mesmo postou uma pergunta sobre como o `yield` modifica uma função, e a resposta que elaborei para essa pergunta demonstra essas diferença. A palavra chave `yield`,e ela, assim como o `async def`, mudam uma coisa uma informação no objeto `function` quando ele é criado que faz com que essas funções sejam completamente diferentes de funções normais quando chamadas. Ao contrário de funções defindas com `def` e com `lambda`, que são identicas em funcionamento. 
Vale a pena ler a resposta lá:

[Como o Python trata o comando "yield" internamente?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/365978/como-o-python-trata-o-comando-yield-internamente/366052#366052)

É interessante notar que a marcação que a linguagem faz para distinguir essas funções é no atribudo `.__code__.co_flags` de uma função - e, novamente, para funções `def` e `lambda` o valor desses flags é o mesmo, refletindo uma vez mais que elas são a mesma coisa:

```
In [60]: def a(): pass                                                                                                         

In [61]: b = lambda : None                                                                                                     

In [62]: a.__code__.co_flags                                                                                                   
Out[62]: 67

In [63]: b.__code__.co_flags                                                                                                   
Out[63]: 67

In [64]: def c(): yield                                                                                                        

In [65]: c.__code__.co_flags                                                                                                   
Out[65]: 99
```

Comment: Gostei muito das suas respostas, e fico lisonjeado pela sua ajuda. Isto esta apontando o caminho para um dia eu entender pelo menos o básico de como o interpretador do Python funciona e como certos mecanismos internos da linguagem se comportam +50

Comment: Escrevi mais uma resposta que acrescenta sobre o funcionamento interno da linguagem hoje: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/368884/m%C3%A9todos-de-uma-classe-s%C3%A3o-recriados-para-cada-inst%C3%A2ncia-no-python/368905#368905