# Métodos de uma classe são recriados para cada instância no Python?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, python-internals

Pelo que observei ao gerar uma instância de uma classe todos os métodos da classe são recriados em uma posição de memória diferente como no trecho abaixo:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__ (self):
        self.x = 10
    def getFoo(self):
        return self.x
    def setFoo(self,xnew):
        self.x = xnew

a = Foo()
b = Foo()

>>> a.getFoo
Out[79]: <bound method Foo.getFoo of <__main__.Foo object at 0x000001C0EF1F6198>>

>>> b.getFoo
Out[80]: <bound method Foo.getFoo of <__main__.Foo object at 0x000001C0EF1F6518>>
```

Porém quando se está fazendo uma varredura, criando e testando muitos objetos objetos desta classe com diferentes parâmetros, isso pode acabar com a memória fazendo com que a execução demore bastante. Existe alguma forma de criar métodos de instância únicos para a classe? 
Eu imaginei que fosse o `@classmethod` (pelo que li em https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Classes.html#classmethod) porém quanto testei também não deu certo:

```
class Foo():
    x = 5
    def __init__ (self):
        self.x = 10
    def getFoo(self):
        return self.x
    @classmethod
    def setFoo(cls,xnew):
        cls.x = xnew

a = Foo()
b = Foo()
print(a.x, b.x,Foo.x) #10 10 5

a.setFoo(29)
print(a.x,b.x,Foo.x)  #10 10 29

print(a.getFoo == b.getFoo) #False
print(a.setFoo == b.setFoo) #True
```

Comment: Só um adendo, em python não usamos getters e setters, neste caso você deveria utilizar properties (isso em casos bem especificos ainda)

Comment: Estou no celular e não consigo responder, mas a ideia é que a classe em si possui funções e quando a classe é instâncias o Python cria um descritor que define o método. Isto é, o `getFoo` da instância será um descritor que faz referência à função original da classe. É esse descritor que é responsável por definir o valor de `self` que será passado como primeiro parâmetro. Ou seja, a função em si não é recriada, o que acontece é que cada instância possui seu próprio descritor, mas todos fazendo referência a mesma função.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr:**

Os métodos são objetos temporários - na verdade são criados
a cada vez que são acessados, com a agregação do atributo `self`
à função que está declarada na classe. Ou seja: um método
de instância de Python sequer existe na memória enquanto
não está em uso, para nenhuma instância de uma classe.

**"calma, não é nada disso que você está pensando"**

Sim, claro que para quem olha o recorte que você fez, uma hipótese lógica
é justamente de que "cada instância tem suas próprias instâncias
de métodos" - e, se fosse realmente isso, sua preocupação
está muito bem colocada - cada instância de uma classe
ocuparia um espaço bem grande de memória com cópias quase
idênticas dos métodos.

Mas nem sempre a primeira hipótese a que chegamos, mesmo que pareça
bem simples, é um fato.

O que acontece é que os objetos do tipo método não são criados
quando a classe é criada, nem quando uma instância é criada. **Métodos são
produzidos em "tempo real" quando são acessados** - seja no contexto
da classe, seja numa instância, e **não consomem memória se não estão em uso**.

Sim, isso pode ter algum impacto na performance,
nada perto do impacto na memória que lhe preocupou, e há formas de mitigar essa
perda de performance se for constatada que ela realmente tem algum impacto no seu código, através de profiling. (E isso também me incomodou muito quando descobri, até constatar que o impacto é realmente mínimo)

Primeiro, vamos continuar o seu achado de que métodos em instâncias diferentes são objetos diferentes: na verdade, o mesmo método, na mesma instância de uma classe, é um objeto diferente ao ser recuperado como um atributo em ocasiões distintas:

```
In [38]: class A: 
    ...:     def b(self): 
    ...:         pass 
    ...:                                                                                                                       

In [39]: a = A()                                                                                                               

In [40]: a.b is a.b                                                                                                            
Out[40]: False
```

**Por que não adianta comparar o `id` dos métodos?**

Eu poderia comparar o `id` dos métodos acima, e o Python imprimir o mesmo resultado - mas isso seria enganoso. Por que ao chamar `id(a.b)`, a função `id` retorna o valor, e o objeto `a.b` que foi passado como parâmetro fica sem nenhuma referência, e é destruido. Uma próxima chamada a `id(a.b)` pode dar azar (ou sorte), e criar o novo método exatamente no mesmo endereço de memória, e a comparação `id(a.b) == id(a.b)` pode resultar em `True`, mesmo os dois `a.b` sendo objetos distintos. Se eu guardar uma referência ao primeiro objeto método, no entanto, o segundo vai ser criado com um id distinto:

```
In [42]: c = a.b                                                                                                               

In [43]: print(id(c), id(a.b), id(a.b))                                                                                        
140180715412680 140180937921736 140180937921736
```

Observe justamente o que descrevi: o primeiro objeto método tem uma referência a mais, na variável `c` - então ele continua existindo depois da chamada de `id(c)`, mas o segundo objeto é destruído no instante em que `id` acaba a sua execução, e a terceira
chamada a `id` recebe um `a.b` exatamente na mesma posição que o da segunda chamada.

**Mácomoéquepode??**

Voltando ao principal - **que mecanismo o Python usa para criar esses objetos método?** Isso talvez seja a parte mais legal de todas: o mecanismo usado internamente pela linguagem é 100% exposto como uma funcionalidade da linguagem, e é customizável em Python puro! Ou seja: você pode criar seus próprios decoradores equivalentes ao `@classmethod` e `@staticmethod` que mudam o comportamento de um método (isso dentre outras possibilidades).

O que a linguagem faz é depender do protocolo de descritores ([descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)): qualquer atributo da classe  (o que inclui funções definidas no corpo da classe), que implemente um método dentre `__get__`, `__set__` ou `__delete__`, quando for recuperado (seja com a notação de "Classe.attr" ou "instancia.attr", ou com "getattr(Classe, 'attr')"), em vez de ser retornado diretamente, tem seu método `__get__` chamado - o que ese  `__get__` retornar é usado como o valor do atributo.

Normalmente, o protocolo de descritores é mais visível quando usamos o  built-in `@property`, que já é justamente um atalho pra transformar um método num objeto descritor que chama aquele método.

No entanto, qualquer função em Python 3 *tem* o método `__get__`, e o que o método `__get__` de uma função faz é justamente transformar a mesma em um método de instância! E um método na verdade é um objeto bem simples: o método `__get__` recebe como parâmetro a instância em que o atributo está sendo acessado - o objeto método guarda essa referência como um atributo, e, quando for chamado (em Python, qualquer objeto que tenha o método `__call__` pode ser chamado), ele chama a função original, passando a instância como primeiro parâmetro. **É aí que o argumento `self` é injetado na chamada de um método**.  (ou seja, o "self" que "parece mágica", usado como parâmetro em todos os métodos, é acrescentado por um mecanismo da linguagem bem documentado para "uso e modificação").

```
In [48]: class A: 
    ...:     def b(self): 
    ...:         pass 
    ...:                                                                                                                       

In [49]: A().b                                                                                                                 
Out[49]: <bound method A.b of <__main__.A object at 0x7f7e9ee2dd30>>

In [50]: A.b                                                                                                                   
Out[50]: <function __main__.A.b(self)>

In [51]: print(dir(A().b))                                                                                                     
['__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__func__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__self__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']

In [52]: A().b.__self__, A().b.__func__                                                                                        
Out[52]: (<__main__.A at 0x7f7e9ee076d8>, <function __main__.A.b(self)>)

In [53]: A().b.__func__ is A.b                                                                                                 
Out[53]: True
```

Ou seja, no momento em que o Python executa a expressão `a.b`, o método `__get__` da função `A.b` é chamado, e recebe como parâmetro `a`. Esse `__get__` então cria o objeto `method`, com os atributos `__func__` e  `__self__` configurados. Quando esse objeto method é chamado, o Python entra em seu método `__call__`, e o que ele executa é equivalente a:

```
def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
    return self.__func__(self.__self__, *args, **kw)
```

(O código em Python de um objeto `method` seria *exatamente* esse, e só não é porque o objeto `method` em si está definido em código C no CPython)

**@classmethod e @staticmethod**

Esses dois built-ins são implementados em código nativo, mas agora dá pra entender como funcionam: você pode fazer o "classmethod" que faz um método receber a *classe* em vez de a instância no primeiro parâmetro criando um objeto que: mantenha uma referência pra função original, e tenha os atributos `__get__` e `__self__` apropriados - veja como fica em poucas linhas:

```
In [29]: class MyClassMethod:
    ...:     def __init__(self, func, owner=None):
    ...:         self.func = func
    ...:         self.owner = owner
    ...:         
    ...:     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
    ...:         # Cria um objeto novo a cada vez que 
    ...:         # o atributo é recuperado - evita problemas
    ...:         # potenciais em programas multithreading
    ...:         # com herança de classes:
    ...:         return MyClassMethod(self.func, owner)
    ...:         # Sem se preocupar com multithreading,
    ...:         # esta função poderia fazer simplesmente:
    ...:         self.owner = owner
    ...:         return self
    ...:     
    ...:     def __call__(self, *args, **kw):
    ...:         print("Método de classe chamado")
    ...:         return self.func(self.owner, *args, **kw)
    ...:     
    ...: 
    ...: class A:
    ...:     @MyClassMethod
    ...:     def b(cls):
    ...:         print(f"Estou na classe {cls!r}")
    ...: 
    ...:         

In [30]: A().b()
Método de classe chamado
Estou na classe <class '__main__.A'>
```

**Custo de memória de uma instância**

Voltando um pouco a sua preocupação inicial: já vimos que cada instância de um objeto não cria cópias dos métodos - o que é que existe na memória para cada objeto então?

Uma instância cria na memória um objeto em Python genérico, que tem uma referência para a sua classe (em Python, a classe é um objeto como qualquer outro), em seu atributo `.__class__`, e cria um novo dicionário no seu atributo `__dict__` e uma estrutura para referenciar as "weakrefs" em `__weakref__`. Além disso, ela tem uma referência a todos os atributos que são setados no `__init__`.

Um dicionário vazio tem cerca de 250 bytes, o `__weakref__` vazio cerca de 80 - e o "PyObject" em si, uns 60 bytes (Python 3.7 64bit - em 32bit esses valores podem ser menores) - ou seja, uma instância "nova" de uma classe comum, vai usar cerca de 390 bytes.

No caso de ser uma instância com atributos bem definidos, que vai ser instanciada muitas vezes (vamos dizer que seja uma `class Point`, que só vai guardar coordenadas "x" e "y" e ter métodos para operar com eles), é possível suprimir a criação do dicionário interno da instância (e do `__weakref__`) - nesse caso, cada instância vai usar só os seus 60 bytes e mais o espaço dos atributos, sem os 250 bytes do `__dict__`. Para isso, é só definir o atributo `__slots__` no corpo da classe - o Python cria uma classe com layout especial, com espaço direto para os atributos pré-definidos, e sem o `__dict__`:

```
In [51]: class BadPoint:
    ...:     def __init__(self, x, y):
    ...:         self.x = x
    ...:         self.y = y
    ...:         

In [52]: class Point:
    ...:     __slots__ = "x", "y"
    ...:     def __init__(self, x, y):
    ...:         self.x = x
    ...:         self.y = y
    ...:     def  distance(self, other):
    ...:          return ((self.x - other.x) ** 2 + (self.y - other.y) ** 2) ** 0.5
    ...: 
    ...:     def __repr__(self):
    ...:          return f"P<{self.x}, {self.y}>"
    ...:     

In [53]: 

In [53]: a = [Point(i, i) for i in range(1000)]

In [54]: get_size(a)
Out[54]: 65024

In [55]: b = [BadPoint(i, i) for i in range(1000)]

In [56]: get_size(b)
Out[56]: 205120
```

(esse get_size é uma função que chama recursivamente o `sys.getsizeof` de um objeto - usei a implementação que está nesta receita: https://goshippo.com/blog/measure-real-size-any-python-object/)

Como pode ver, os métodos a mais não fazem diferença no tamanho - só existe uma cópia do "original" deles (como objetos do tipo função) na classe. Por outro lado, suprimir o dicionário interno faz bastante diferença em objetos simples.

**Otimizações possíveis**

Como escrito acima, é possível que essa criação/destruição de objetos do tipo método possa ter impacto em algum trecho de uma aplicação - em geral somente se dentro de um outro trecho de código vamos chamar várias vezes o mesmo método de uma mesma instância (isso é, dentro de um laço `for` ou `while`).

E nesses casos, tudo o que você precisa fazer para evitar o desperdício de recursos é manter uma referência para o método que exista durante o laço.
Ou seja, em vez de:

```
for character in big_text:
    myobject.transmogrify(character)
```

basta escrever:

```
transmogrify = myobject.transmogrify
for character in big_text:
    transmogrify(character)
```

Perceba que essa mesma ideia vale para qualquer acesso a atributo, na verdade - já que cada vez que escrevemos `instancia.atributo`,  a linguagem tem  que verificar várias coisas, inclusive se o atributo é um descritor, antes de recuperar o  atributo.  O simples fato de se colocar o atributo num variável local antes do `for` faz esse mecanismo ser usado uma única vez em vez de uma vez em cada repetição.

Comment: Eu não poderia ter explicado melhor +1!

Comment: Engordei ela mais um pouquinho agora.

Answer (score -3):

caso curioso, sugiro usar função para criar função. minha sugestão é o seguinte codigo

```
class Foo():
    x = 5
    def __init__ (self):
        self.x = 10
        self.setFoo = self.setarFoo()

    def getFoo(self):
        return self.x

    def setarFoo(self):
        def setFoo(xnew):
            self.x = xnew
        return setFoo


a = Foo()
b = Foo()
print(a.x, b.x,Foo.x) 

a.setFoo(29)
print(a.x,b.x,Foo.x)  

print(a.getFoo == b.getFoo) 
print(a.setFoo == b.setFoo)
```

veja que o `__init__` chama a função `setarFoo`, e `setarFoo` returna a função criada em sua chamada

`@classmethod` se ñ estou enganado é para adicionar um novo `construtor` à classe

Comment: Sua resposta não responde ao que foi perguntado, muito menos faz sentido fazer o que fez, de criar uma função para definir outra função.

Comment: minha compreensão é que o objetivo era ter métodos únicos para objetos da mesma classe

Comment: Sim, mas isso já acontece por padrão, vide resposta do jsbueno.

Comment: desconhecia esta parte

Comment: Se for manter a resposta, por favor, ao menos arrume a identação. O que está aí não é Python válido.