# O que significa um "bound method"?

Tags: python, terminologia, método

O que é um ***bound method*** em Python?
Qual a diferença entre métodos ***bound*** e ***static***?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Um *bound method* é simplesmente uma função que é um atributo de uma classe e é acessada por uma de suas instâncias. Ex:

```py
class X:
    def f(self):
        pass

print(X.f) # function
print(X().f) # bound method
```

Ou seja, se eu acesso a função como `X.f` (nome da classe e nome da função), ela é uma função "normal". Mas se eu acessá-la através de uma instância (`X()`), ela passa a ser um *bound method*.

A diferença é que em um *bound method* o primeiro argumento da função sempre é a instância que está fazendo a chamada. Por exemplo:

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val
    def f(self):
        print(self.val)

instancia = X(5)
instancia.f() # 5

# chamando f() com outras instâncias
X(10).f() # 10
X(42).f() # 42
```

Ou seja, estou chamando `f()` sem nenhum argumento, mas como a chamada é feita a partir de uma instância da classe `X`, então `f` é um *bound method*, o que significa que a instância será automaticamente passada para a função como o primeiro argumento.

> No fundo, `instancia.f()` é o mesmo que `X.f(instancia)` (chamar o método `f` da classe `X`, passando a instância `instancia` como primeiro argumento).

Vale lembrar ainda que a função/método não precisa necessariamente ser definido dentro da classe, pois também é possível fazer isso:

```py
# função genérica que imprime o atributo "val" do objeto que for passado para ela
def func(self):
    print(self.val)

class X:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

X.f = func

instancia = X(5)
instancia.f() # 5

# só pra embananar ainda mais: outra classe que também tem "val"
class Y:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

Y.whatever = func

y = Y(10)
y.whatever() # 10
```

Claro que eu também poderia fazer `func(instancia)` ou `func(y)`. Isso é só para mostrar o mecanismo do *bound method*: a função é um atributo da classe e foi chamada através de uma instância desta. Por isso esta instância é passada como o primeiro argumento da função.

---

Mas e se eu quisesse chamar um método `X.f()` sem argumentos (ou sem que o primeiro argumento seja necessariamente uma instância de `X`)?
Basta fazer com que o método seja `static`:

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    @staticmethod
    def f():
        print('bla')

X.f() # bla

# agora não é mais bound, nem se for acessado por uma instância
print(X.f) # function
print(X(5).f) # function
```

---

Apenas para complementar, vamos ver o que acontece se o método `f` recebe vários argumentos:

```py
class X:
    def __init__(self, val):
        self.val = val

    @staticmethod
    def static(a, b, c):
        print(a, b, c)

    def bound(self, a, b, c):
        print(self.val, a, b, c)

instancia = X(5)
instancia.bound(1, 2, 3) # 5 1 2 3
X.static(1, 2, 3) # 1 2 3
# sim, podemos chamar o método estático através da instância (o self também não é passado, pois não é bound)
instancia.static(1, 2, 3) # 1 2 3

# erro, pois eu passei "1" no lugar do self
X.bound(1, 2, 3) # TypeError: bound() missing 1 required positional argument: 'c'
# o correto é
X.bound(instancia, 1, 2, 3) # 5 1 2 3
```

Ou seja, o método `bound`, quando acessado a partir de uma instância, é um *bound method*: a instância é passada como o primeiro argumento, e os demais são colocados em seguida (`instancia.bound(1, 2, 3)` é o mesmo que chamar `X.bound(instancia, 1, 2, 3)`).

Já o método `static` é estático, e por isso não é *bound* (não há a passagem da instância como primeiro argumento).

---

Para entender melhor o mecanismo que injeta o `self` automaticamente (e vários outros detalhes), [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/368884/112052).

Comment: Inclusive, se eu não estou enganado, a função dentro da classe na verdade será tratada como um descritor em que o get fará o bound com a instância retornando o partial que define o valor de self. Lembro de já ter visto isto, mas agora não sei se foi no fonte do python ou um exemplo de "código equivalente" que reproduzira o mesmo comportamento

Comment: @Woss Adicionei um link no final da resposta, acho que lá explica tudo, né?

Comment: sim, acredito que sim. Por isso que eu lembrava, fui eu mesmo que disse isso aqui hahaha

Comment: @Woss, eu achei [isso na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#partial-objects): objetos  partial são como objetos function no sentido de que podem ser chamados, fracamente referenciáveis ​​e podem ter atributos. Existem algumas diferenças importantes. Por exemplo, os atributos __name__e __doc__não são criados automaticamente. Além disso, os objetos partial **definidos em classes se comportam como métodos estáticos** e não se transformam em métodos vinculados(bounded methods) durante a consulta de atributo de instância.