# Por que utilizamos decoradores em Python?

Tags: python, decorator-pattern

Ao estudar python e trabalhar com algumas bibliotecas em algum momento a gente se depara com decoradores.

Mesmo estudando sobre o assunto, nunca cheguei em uma situação que necessariamente iria precisar utilizar e/ou implementar um decorador.

Sendo assim:

Em quais situações idealmente são necessárias a implementação de um decorador? Por que?

Comment: Existem situações demais para caber tudo em uma resposta. O link indicado acima no box azul dá uma ideia inicial, e tem mais uns exemplos [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/368884/112052), acho que já deve ser um bom começo...

Comment: Muito obrigado!