# Como iteradores criados a partir de listas resgatam valores "aleatórios" em Python?

Tags: python, lista, iterator

Estou estudando iteradores e geradores em Python, e fiquei intrigado com uma questão, e não acho a resposta para isso em nenhum lugar.

Quando criamos um gerador em Python através de uma expressão geradora como `(x**2 for x in range(50))`, temos uma expressão matemática, uma lei que o programa consegue utilizar para calcular o próximo valor, se demandado. O mesmo acontece se criarmos o gerador por uma função geradora, como:

```
def quadrados(n, max):
    while n < max:
        yield n**2
```

Enfim, em ambos os casos o computador tem uma receita de bolo, um passo a passo que ele segue para gerar o próximo item. Acredito que o mesmo aconteça ao se criar um iterador com uma classe.

A pergunta é, como um iterador criado a partir de uma lista de valores aleatórios, por exemplo, consegue "produzir" os próximos valores?
Se definimos um iterador como `it = iter([95, 27, 2348, 32, 27])`, como ele consegue resgatar os itens sem eles estarem salvos na memória? Se ele simplesmente acessa essa lista e obtém o valor, é porque esse valor está salvo na memória, não?

Comment: Eu não conheço a fundo os *internals* do Python, mas tanto `iter` quanto os geradores devem guardar os valores (o seu estado) em memória. No caso do `iter`, vc passou uma lista (pois está delimitado por `[ ]`), e provavelmente ele cria um objeto que mantém uma referência para esta lista. Não imagino outra forma dele conseguir iterar pelos valores, a não ser mantendo-os internamente como parte do objeto criado.

Comment: é a única forma que consigo imaginar também. mas nesse caso os valores estariam sendo salvos na memória, o que me parece um pouco contraditório, pois se entendi bem o conceito, os iteradores não guardam todos os dados na memória, e por isso são mais leves e rápidos do que listas, por exemplo.

Comment: Mas qdo vc faz `iter([1, 2, 3])`, a lista `[1, 2, 3]` **já foi criada**, então não tem como economizar nada aí, pois a memória já foi "gasta"... Não tem nada de contraditório

Comment: Dei uma fuçada no [código fonte do CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) e coloquei [uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/513942/112052) dando mais detalhes...

Comment: TL;DR: quand você passa uma lista para o iter, o iterador da listta mantém uma referência pra ela. Então ela só é destruída quando o iterador também for (quando sair de escopo, ou com um `del`). Não tem surpresas aí: só manter a mesma regra sempre: um objeto existe enquanto tem referências pra ele.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro, um pouco de terminologia/conceitos.

[De acordo com a documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typeiter), um ***iterator*** (ou "iterador") é qualquer objeto que implemente os métodos `__next__` e `__iter__` (sendo que este último deve retornar o próprio objeto, enquanto o primeiro retorna o próximo item do *iterator*, ou lança um [`StopIteration`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#StopIteration) quando não há mais elementos).

Já um [***generator***](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator) (ou "gerador") é uma função (e portanto também é chamada de *generator function*) que retorna um ***generator iterator*** (que a [documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-generator-iterator) define como "Um objeto criado por uma *generator function*"). Uma *generator function* é criada usando-se o `yield`, que já é explicado em detalhes [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365978/112052) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/92921/112052).

E existe também a [***generator expression***](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), que é uma expressão que retorna um *generator* (como a que tem na pergunta: `(x**2 for x in range(50))`).

Todo objeto *generator iterator* (seja criado por uma *generator function* ou uma *generator expression*) é também um *iterator*. Mas nem todo *iterator* é um *generator*.

---

Um *generator* é *lazy* no sentido de que ele só retorna o próximo valor se você chamar o método `__next__` (seja explicitamente através do [*builtin* `next`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next), ou implicitamente, quando você o percorre com um `for` por exemplo). Internamente ele guarda o seu estado (basicamente, "onde ele parou" e o valor de cada variável naquele ponto; leia o [link já indicado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/365978/112052) para saber mais detalhes), para que na próxima chamada de `next` ele possa continuar a execução de onde parou.

Em geral um *generator* não guarda todos os valores de uma vez na memória, gerando-os sob demanda. Mas nada impede que você faça isso:

```
# itera pelos elementos do iterável uma ou mais vezes
def ciclo(iteravel, repetir=1):
    # guarda os valores do iterável em uma lista
    valores = list(iteravel)
    for _ in range(repetir):
        for n in valores:
            yield n

# imprime duas vezes os valores da generator expression
for n in ciclo((x ** 2 for x in range(3)), 2):
    print(n)
```

Ou seja, a *generator function* `ciclo` cria um *generator* que itera várias vezes pelo iterável informado. Os valores são guardados em uma lista porque o `iteravel` pode ser outro *generator* (que só pode ser iterado uma vez), então guardando os valores em uma lista eu garanto que posso iterar várias vezes sem problemas. No exemplo acima, se eu fizesse o segundo `for` diretamente no `iteravel`, os valores só seriam retornados uma vez, já que a *generator expression* cria um *generator*, e este só pode ser iterado uma vez.

Ou seja, eu criei um *generator* que guarda todos os valores em memória de uma vez (só por curiosidade, é exatamente isso que a [função `itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) faz).

Claro que isso é um *corner case*, e em geral, os *generators* não guardam todos os valores na memória (a menos que eu force isso, como fiz acima), computando-os apenas quando necessário. Já um *iterator* que não é um *generator*, não necessariamente será *lazy*.

Quando você faz `iter([1, 2, 3])`, ele retorna um *iterator*, que não é um *generator*, como pode ser verificado com o [módulo `inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html):

```
import inspect

# iter cria um iterator que não é generator
x = iter([1, 30, 99, 42])
print(inspect.isgenerator(x)) # False

# generator expression cria um generator
x = (x * 2 for x in range(10))
print(inspect.isgenerator(x)) # True
```

Além disso, a lista `[1, 2, 3]` já foi criada e internamente o *iterator* mantém uma referência para ela. O que o *iterator* faz é iterar para o próximo elemento quando o método `__next__` é chamado, mas como a lista já foi criada, você não tem a "economia de memória". Um *iterator* só economizaria memória se os seus valores fossem computados sob demanda, como o exemplo do *generator* acima. Por exemplo:

```
# iterator que gera os valores sob demanda
class Squares(object):
    def __init__(self, start, stop):
        self.start = start
        self.stop = stop

    def __iter__(self): return self

    # o próximo elemento é calculado somente se next for chamado
    def __next__(self):
        if self.start >= self.stop:
            raise StopIteration
        current = self.start * self.start
        self.start += 1
        return current

iterator = Squares(3, 10)
print(next(iterator)) # 9
print(next(iterator)) # 16
```

<sup>Se eu usar [`inspect.isgenerator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#inspect.isgenerator) no *iterator* acima, o resultado será `False`.</sup>

Mas se você cria um *iterator* com base nos valores de uma lista, e esta lista já foi criada, aí não tem como economizar nada mesmo. Então a sua pergunta "*como ele consegue resgatar os itens sem eles estarem salvos na memória?*" parte de uma premissa errada, pois os valores estão sim na memória, e é assim que o *iterator* consegue recuperá-los.

---

Indo um pouco mais a fundo, fui dar uma olhada no [código fonte do CPython](https://github.com/python/cpython) (que é a implementação de referência da linguagem, e muito provavelmente a que você está usando). Consultei o código hoje (11/jun/2021):

O *builtin* `iter` está definido [aqui](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c):

```c
static PyObject *
builtin_iter(PyObject *self, PyObject *const *args, Py_ssize_t nargs)
{
    PyObject *v;

    if (!_PyArg_CheckPositional("iter", nargs, 1, 2))
        return NULL;
    v = args[0];
    if (nargs == 1)
        return PyObject_GetIter(v);
    if (!PyCallable_Check(v)) {
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError,
                        "iter(v, w): v must be callable");
        return NULL;
    }
    PyObject *sentinel = args[1];
    return PyCallIter_New(v, sentinel);
}
```

No caso, quando passamos apenas um argumento (por exemplo, uma lista), ele cai no `if (nargs == 1)` e chama `PyObject_GetIter`, que por sua vez é definido [aqui](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/abstract.c):

```c
PyObject *
PyObject_GetIter(PyObject *o)
{
    PyTypeObject *t = Py_TYPE(o);
    getiterfunc f;

    f = t->tp_iter;
    if (f == NULL) {
        if (PySequence_Check(o))
            return PySeqIter_New(o);
        return type_error("'%.200s' object is not iterable", o);
    }
    else {
        PyObject *res = (*f)(o);
        if (res != NULL && !PyIter_Check(res)) {
            PyErr_Format(PyExc_TypeError,
                         "iter() returned non-iterator "
                         "of type '%.100s'",
                         Py_TYPE(res)->tp_name);
            Py_DECREF(res);
            res = NULL;
        }
        return res;
    }
}
```

No caso, `o` é a lista, cujo `Py_TYPE(o)` é `PyList_Type`, que por sua vez é definido [aqui](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c):

```c
PyTypeObject PyList_Type = {
    // um monte de linhas...
    list_iter,                                  /* tp_iter */
    // mais um monte de linhas...
```

Veja que no campo `tp_iter` o valor é a função `list_iter`. Como esta função não é nula, a função `PyObject_GetIter` cai no `else` e chama a função `list_iter`, passando a lista como argumento. E essa função (definida no [mesmo arquivo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c) que define o `PyList_Type`) faz o seguinte:

```c
static PyObject *
list_iter(PyObject *seq)
{
    listiterobject *it;

    if (!PyList_Check(seq)) {
        PyErr_BadInternalCall();
        return NULL;
    }
    it = PyObject_GC_New(listiterobject, &PyListIter_Type);
    if (it == NULL)
        return NULL;
    it->it_index = 0;
    Py_INCREF(seq);
    it->it_seq = (PyListObject *)seq;
    _PyObject_GC_TRACK(it);
    return (PyObject *)it;
}
```

E é na linha `it->it_seq = (PyListObject *)seq;` que vemos que a lista (`seq`) é atribuída para o campo `it_seq` do *iterator*. Ou seja, o *iterator* mantém uma referência para a lista. Definição do `listiterobject` (também no [mesmo arquivo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c) que define o `list_iter`):

```c
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    Py_ssize_t it_index;
    PyListObject *it_seq; /* Set to NULL when iterator is exhausted */
} listiterobject;
```

E a implementação do método `next` (também no [mesmo arquivo](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Objects/listobject.c) que define o `list_iter`):

```c
static PyObject *
listiter_next(listiterobject *it)
{
    PyListObject *seq;
    PyObject *item;

    assert(it != NULL);
    seq = it->it_seq;
    if (seq == NULL)
        return NULL;
    assert(PyList_Check(seq));

    if (it->it_index < PyList_GET_SIZE(seq)) {
        item = PyList_GET_ITEM(seq, it->it_index);
        ++it->it_index;
        Py_INCREF(item);
        return item;
    }

    it->it_seq = NULL;
    Py_DECREF(seq);
    return NULL;
}
```

Que mostra que o *iterator* vai percorrendo os elementos da lista um a um.

---

Ou seja, o *iterator* guarda uma referência da lista, e é assim que ele consegue retornar os seus elementos. Como a lista já foi criada, não há a geração *lazy* (sob demanda), como ocorre com os *generators* (ou com o *iterator* `Squares` do exemplo acima), pois os valores já foram criados anteriormente quando você criou a lista.

Answer (score 1):

Você parece estar se confundindo um pouco ao falar de **geradores** e **iteradores**.

Você está certo em falar que **geradores** geram seus valores de forma dinâmica, isto, é, se tivermos a função geradora (editei para evitar um loop infinito):

```
def quadrados(n, max):
    while n < max:
        yield n**2
        n += 1
```

E você iterar sobre essa função geradora dessa forma:

```
for quadrado in quadrados(2, 10):
    print(quadrado)
```

A cada execução do `for loop`, o Python acessa o corpo da função `quadrados`,  vai até a linha com `yield` e retorna o valor para ser usado no seu `for loop`.

O importante de entender aqui é que, no momento entre o `yield` e o final do bloco dentro do `for loop`, a função `quadrados` está efetivamente **pausada**: o gerador economiza espaço em memória porque ao invés de ter que guardar todos os valores resultantes, ele guarda simplesmente o **estado atual da função**. A função `quadrados` está lá, "congelada", esperando o momento em que vai poder continuar a executar - o que acontece no momento em que o bloco dentro do `for loop` termina e você passa para a próxima execução.

Por outro lado, uma **expressão geradora** como `(x**2 for x in range(50))` é apenas uma forma mais simples de escrever uma "pseudo função geradora" em uma linha. Se tentarmos iterar sobre essa expressão, Python lidará com os valores da mesma forma: gera um valor, "congela" o estado do gerador, trabalha com o valor, "descongela" o gerador e gera o próximo valor, ...

Quando você deu seu exemplo com `it = iter([95, 27, 2348, 32, 27])`, note que aqui **não estamos falando de geradores**, mas sim de **iteradores**, que são simplesmente objetos sobre os quais podemos iterar com um `for loop`. Nesse seu exemplo, a lista `[95, 27, 2348, 32, 27]` é sim criada e mantida em memória, pois ela é referenciada pelo próprio iterador, mesmo que você explicitamente não a tenha referenciado por uma variável como `my_list = [95, 27, 2348, 32, 27]`. Este seu exemplo não envolve geradores em nenhum momento, e portanto o espaço em memória é imediatamente ocupado pela lista no momento em que é declarada.

Ok, mas e se agora combinarmos as coisas utilizando uma **expressão geradora** como `it = iter(x**2 for x in range(50))`? Nesse caso, tanto os valores originais do seu `range(50)` quanto os valores resultantes da expressão `x**2 for x in range(50)` estão dentro de geradores. Então Python só precisa ir "congelando" e "descongelando" os geradores para conseguir iterar sobre eles, sem precisar alocar todos os elementos na memória.

Comment: tecnicamente não existe isso de que geradores não possam ter um estado interno que use memória. É só wishfull thinking do A.P. por conta de exemplos curtos  e simples de geradores, muito populares na documentação.